# determine if android activity was opened "for result"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

in some instances I want my activity (activity A) to `setResult` and other times I want my activity to `startActivity` and sent an intent with some parameters while calling finish on itself.

I can solve this problem by starting this activity A with some bundle paramaters, if that parameter exists then `setResult` else `startActivity` but now I am curious if there is anyway to check the intent for how it was started in the first place

Is there a way to determine if my activity A was started for result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `getCallingActivity()` will return the activity that called your activity using `startActivityForResult(...)` . If `getCallingActivity()` is null you can assume your activity was started as normal (no result expected)

[getCallingActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29)

Ex.

```
ComponentName callingComponent = getCallingActivity();

if (callingComponent == null) // result not expected
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    // set your intent extras here
    startActivity(intent);
} else { //result expected
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // set your intent extras here
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```